# Could not convert BSON document to a PHP variable

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I have written mongoDB query in laravel,

```
     $pipeline = array(
            array(
                '$match' => array(
                    '$and' => array(
                        array('CID' => '000001'),
                        array('ID' => 'C00001'),
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $result=  mongodb_connection_new("NP_Segment",$pipeline);
```

My other queries are responding properly with data, but for fetching following data from collection, above query is giving error.
Data in collection

```
   { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("589dd9ac7ffbe03495c2dbd7"), 
    "ID" : "C00001", 
    "CID" : "000001", 
    "MinTs" : ISODate("2017-02-10T20:47:37.000+0000"), 
    "MaxTs" : ISODate("2017-02-10T21:19:46.000+0000"), 
    "value" : [
        {
            "IP" : "10.179.158.202", 
            "From" : "PANEL", 
            "To" : "CAMS", 
            "RDt" : ISODate("2017-02-10T21:19:46.000+0000"), 
            "CDt" : ISODate("2017-02-10T15:49:52.312+0000"), 
            "Status" : "", 
            "MacID" : "031R", 
            "HexMsg" : "\n�E0210\"SIA-DCS\"0110R000001L000001#C00001[C00001|NYY0032|031R|032R|033U|034U|035R|036R|037U|038U|039U|040U|041U|042U|043U|044U|045U|046U|047U|048U|049U|050U|051U|052U|053U|054B|055U|056R|057U|099R]_21:19:46,10-02-2017\r", 
            "HexReply" : "\n��0032\"ACK\"0110R000001L000001#C00001[]\r", 
            "ZoneNo" : "", 
            "ID" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Error : **Could not convert BSON document to a PHP variable**